# How to change ngModel value on double click?

Tags: html, angular, event-handling, frontend, angular-ngmodel

When i click on a input tag with [(ngModel)] in it, it sets a caret and the user can change the value. How do i make it so that the caret is set on double click instead of one? The single click should start a function.
What i have right now:

```
<input name="name" value="" [(ngModel)]="someName"  (dblclick)="openFolder(folder)"/>
```

I want to reverse what the [(ngModel)] and (dblclick) events do.

Comment: SS o this is called or not (dblclick)="openFolder(folder)"/>

Comment: i want to call openFolder with (click). And on double click edit someName

Comment: Then do the same for two event seperate click and dblclick event

Comment: my edit happens on click, how can i set it to a double click?